# How do I prove that $3n\log(n!) \in O(n^2\log n)$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

How do I prove that $3n\log(n!) \in O(n^2\log n)$?

Based on simpler exercises I did, it involves finding $n_0$ and $c$ such that $t(n) \leq c * n^2$ if we wanted to prove that $t(n) \in O(n^2)$.

Now I try to apply this in the above situation we would like to find a $c$ that makes this $3n\log(n!) \leq c \times (n^2\log n) $ true.

I have no idea what to do to find $c$ and the $n!$ bothers me because I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Could you take for granted that log(n!)~nlog(n),n->inf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that $n!=1\cdot 2\cdots n\le n^n$. Therefore, $\log(n!)\le n\log(n)$. From that, we can conclude that 
$$3n\log(n!)\le 3n^2\log(n)$$